# Running a mapreduce job no output at all. It doesn't even run . very weird. no error thrown on the terminal

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I compiled the mapreduce code (driver, mapper and reducer classes) and created Jar files. When I run it on the dataset, it doesn't seem to run. It just comes back to the prompt as shown in the image. Any suggestions folks?

thanks much
basam

[image]

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

//This driver program will bring all the information needed to submit this Map reduce job.

public class MultiLangDictionary {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    if (args.length !=2){

        System.err.println("Usage: MultiLangDictionary <input path> <output path>");

        System.exit(-1);            

    }



    Configuration conf = new Configuration();



    Job ajob = new Job(conf, "MultiLangDictionary");

     //Assigning the driver class name
    ajob.setJarByClass(MultiLangDictionary.class);


    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(ajob, new Path(args[0]));

    //first argument is the job itself
    //second argument is the location of the output dataset
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(ajob, new Path(args[1]));


    ajob.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);



    ajob.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);


    //Defining the mapper class name
    ajob.setMapperClass(MultiLangDictionaryMapper.class);

    //Defining the Reducer class name
    ajob.setReducerClass(MultiLangDictionaryReducer.class);

    //setting the second argument as a path in a path variable
    Path outputPath = new Path(args[1]);

    //deleting the output path automatically from hdfs so that we don't have delete it explicitly
    outputPath.getFileSystem(conf).delete(outputPath);



}

}
```

Comment: Are you submitting the job? In the above code there is no job submission.

Comment: Petros, The job submission statement is in the image file that is in this post

Comment: Is hadoop acutally running , try running `hadoop fs -ls /` or `jps`. What it gives?

Answer (score 0):

try with java packagename.classname in the command

```
hadoop jar MultiLangDictionary.jar [yourpackagename].MultiLangDictionary input output
```

Comment: Ashok, I have been running hadoop jar files the way I ran this program also. And they are all successfull. I can't understand why this one is failing. Is there any size limit on length of Jar file name or input file name or length of driver program name? Just thinking loudly

Comment: I dont think the job is failing with the file name length issues. Can you pls check the job logs in webui, so that you may be able to trace out the possible eror.

Comment: Ashok, If the job didnt' even run, how can I check the job log?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the Map and Reduce output key types to your driver. Something like (this is an example):

```
job2.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job2.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job2.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
```

In the above both the Mapper and Reducer would be writing `(Text,Text)` in their `context.write()` methods.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks much. I will keep you posted as soon as I complete running the code. But I can't mark as helpful. stackflow is not letting me do that.

Comment: I added two lines but that didn't help. :     //Output types  

        ajob.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);

        ajob.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);